# GetTo and GetROProerty are geeting property values from Object Repository in QTP?

Tags: qtp

GetToProerty and GetROProerty are geeting property values from OR in QTP, i get below line from QTP help

> 'The following example uses the
>   GetTOProperty method to retrieve the 
>   'RegExpWndClass property from the
>   Object Repository.

now i am using test script using DP, when i am getting text property of an object it shows empty [IN Flight Application the order is successfully inserted]

> insertValue = Window("text:= Flight
>   Reservation").WinEdit("attachedText:=
>   Order No:").GetTOProperty("text")

Is Really get the GetToProperty from Object Repository? How go get the property values in DP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,"GetTOProperty" will get the Property value from the Test Object stored in the OR. If you are using DP , than it will get the Value as NULL. I never verified it, But this is What i think it should.

if you want to get the Value of an object During RO, than you can get it like:\

```
insertValue = Window("text:= Flight Reservation").WinEdit("attachedText:= Order No:").GetROProperty("text")
```

This will get you the value of object property during Run time.